# How to create URL like http://api.example.com

Tags: url, web, dns, subdomain, cpanel

I have bought domain at `cpanel`  I need to create the API path like  `http://api.example.com` to create API for my database. where I should create folder called API in `cpanel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create `subdomain` at `cpanel` then your new folder will be created at `/home/vacation/public_html/api/`
then create API files like this

`/home/vacation/public_html/api/get.php`

Answer (score 1):

In your public httpfolder create a folder called api. Then in cpanel set that folder as a subdomain, also called api.

It can then be accessed either from api.domain.com or domain.com/api